# Showing that $A(p)\circ A(q)=p \circ q$ for every $p,q\in \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{x_A,y_A,z_A\}$ be an orthonormal set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We call the coordinate system by these vectors $A$. Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$. We define $ A(v)$ to be the unique vector with components $a,b,c$ such that $v=ax_A+by_A+cz_A$ (uniqueness follows because $\{x_A,y_A,z_A\}$ is a base) . It follows easily from orthogonality relations that $a=x_A\circ  v,b=y_A\circ v,c=z_A \circ v$ .

Now I believe that the following is true:

For any two vectors $p,q\in \mathbb{R}^3$, $A(p)\circ A(q)=p \circ q$.

Things get messy when I try to prove it. Is there a smart way to see this ?

Thank you

---

Note: I am currently taking a robotics course, to which knowledge of rotation matrices is useful. I never learnt anything about rotation matrices before. I only took a weak non-rigorous engineering linear algebra course.  Thus, I  would like to see a proof without assuming knowledge about rotation matrices. My robotics book introduces rotation matrices in a non-rigorous, and I'd like to make things very rigorous. Thanks for your help.

Comment: $\circ$ is the standard inner product, $$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} \circ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = ax + by + cz,$$ or is it some other inner product?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes it is. However, I guess this should hold for all inner products.

Comment: Yes, it should. But with the standard inner product, I see a particularly direct proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer Will you argument rest on the belief that the angle between two vectors does not change by changing the orientation ? :)

Comment: No, it's a purely algebraic argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, we have

$$p = (x_A \circ p)\cdot x_A + (y_A\circ p)\cdot y_A + (z_A \circ p)\cdot z_A,$$

and $$A(p) = \begin{pmatrix}x_A\circ p\\y_A\circ p\\z_A\circ p \end{pmatrix},$$

and similar for $q$.

So we have

$$\begin{align}
A(p)\circ A(q) &= (x_A\circ p)\cdot (x_A\circ q) + (y_A\circ p)\cdot(y_A\circ q) + (z_A\circ p)\cdot(z_A\circ q)\\
&= ((x_A\circ p)\cdot x_A)\circ q + ((y_A\circ p)\cdot y_A)\circ q + ((z_A\circ p)\cdot z_A)\circ q\\
&= ((x_A \circ p)\cdot x_A + (y_A\circ p)\cdot y_A + (z_A \circ p)\cdot z_A)\circ q\\
&= p\circ q
\end{align}$$

by the bilinearity of the inner product.

Comment: haha excellent.

Comment: Regarding your comment "But with the standard inner product, I see a particularly direct proof", your proof works for inner product spaces as well, doesn't it ?

Comment: Ah, actually, $A(v)$ being defined as it is, upon looking closer, you only have $A(p)\circ A(q) = p\circ q$ if the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is orthonormal, so only with the standard product. What generally holds is that if $A(v) = a\cdot e_1 + b\cdot e_2 + c\cdot e_3$ with $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ being an orthonormal base, then you have $A(p)\circ A(q) = p\circ q$. How to explain it, $A$ must be a change of basis between two orthonormal bases.